# URL rewriting in Yii2 not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Yii2 Advanced application and how can I convert this URL

http://192.168.1.190/qjyii2/yii2dev3/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/login

to

http://192.168.1.190/qjyii2/yii2dev3/frontend/web/site/login.php\

I used the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^qjyii2/yii2dev3/frontend/web/([^/]*)\.php$ /qjyii2/yii2dev3/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

And the following Yii setup in frontend/config/main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 
        'showScriptName' => false, // Remove index.php from url
        'suffix' => '.php', // Add suffix to all routes (globally)
    ],
```

And, this didn't work

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` located (in which directory).

Comment: Located under www/qjyii2/yii2dev3/

Comment: If that's the case shouldn't your rule look something like: `frontend/web/([^/]*)\.php$ /qjyii2/yii2dev3/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: @Cyclone - still not working

Comment: @Cyclone - Please have a look at this http://pastebin.com/Q5kXwrqn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add following code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Full  .htaccess file as follows

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-type"
</IfModule>

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Then Set in your main.php params as follows

```
 'defaultController' => 'site',

// uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                'login'=>array('site/login'),
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

Sample config file as follows

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'JBi Test Web Application',
    'defaultController' => 'site',
    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'elby1234',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),

    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(

        'user'=>array(
            'loginUrl'=>array('login'),
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(

                'login'=>array('site/login'),

                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),


        // database settings are configured in database.php
        'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),

    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
        'listPerPage'=> 3,
    ),
);
```

Comment: This is not the answer to this question. OP asked for Yii2 and you have provided solution for Yii 1.1 . THIS WILL NOT WORK EVER.